# ScriptableObject's custom objects begin reset to default?

Tags: unity, scriptable-object

I'm using `ScriptableObject`s as a way to serialize objects that I work with in an editor script. I save them as assets using `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` and get them
resetted
It is saving correctly native c# class objects like strings, primitives and arrays of primitives.

The problem is that my `ScriptableObject` also contains objects of custom classes and structs of my code. These custom objects are being set to `default()` (ie. value types being set to `0` and reference types to `null`) every time the code is recompiled and when the editor is restarted (while the primitive variables still have the right saved value). Even with blittable structs the problem persists.

Is that expected?

**Edit with some code to contextualize**:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct MeshHeader
{
    public int numBones;
    public int numVerts;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string s1 { get; set; }
    public string s2 { get; set; }
}

public class MySO : ScriptableObject
{
    public int myInt; // OK
    public int[] myArr; // OK
    
    // These 2 variables will have their value reset after any recompilation of the code
    public MeshHeader meshHeader; // This will become 0;0
    public MyClass myClass; // This will become null
    
    public static void SaveMySO(MeshHeader h, MyClass c)
    {
        var mySO = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<MySO>();
        mySO.myInt = 10;
        mySO.myArr = new int[2] { 9, 8 };
        mySO.meshHeader = h;
        mySO.myClass = c;
        
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(mySO, "Assets/foo.asset");
    }
    
    public static MySO LoadMySO()
    {
        return AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<MySO>("Assets/foo.asset");
    }
}
```

When I call `MySO.SaveMySO` it will save the `ScriptableObject`. However if I run `MySO.LoadMySO` after any code recompilation between these two calls, it will have both `meshHeader` and `myClass` values set to default, which will be `0` and `null` respectively while still holding the right values for `myInt` and `myArr`.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal complete verifiable example of the problem? That will help us check whether you've correctly set up your custom types for serialization by Unity's serializer. You may also want to look into the [ScriptableSingleton](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/186861/39518) that's made for storing data used by editor utilities.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry for the delay. Just updated the question with a minimal verifiable example of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes in your code sample:

1. You're missing `[System.Serializable]` attributes above your custom types. This flags the type to be serialized so that its data can be saved to disc or preserved and restored after an assembly reload.
2. You're using C# auto-properties, which are not supported by Unity's serializer. Add a serialized backing field for them.

Here's an example with these fixes applied:

```
[System.Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct MeshHeader
{
    public int numBones;
    public int numVerts;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [SerializeField]
    string _s1;
    public string s1 { get {return _s1;} set {_s1 = value;} }

    [SerializeField]
    string _s2;
    public string s2 { get {return _s2;} set {_s2 = value;} }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! hanks for the help DMGregory!

Comment: May I ask how would I know that? I couldn't find anything about applying this specific attribute so my types can be stored properly using the `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset()` in unity docs!

Comment: [It's documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) and covered in [tutorials on the topic](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/editor/custom-data/).

Comment: Thanks again sir!