# Where is the right place to store Unity Custom Editor Window meta data?

Tags: unity, editors

I'm writing a node editor for unity, an Animator window clone if you will. I'm wondering where to store metadata like how the nodes are placed in the editor or what the last selected node was. I can ignore the second example, but the first example is something that has to be saved. I have thought of several options, none of which really satisfies my perfectionist brain.

The first is to store this data inside the node data itself. The nodes are being stored in a **ScriptableObject**, so I can just add a couple of attributes there for the editor window. However, this seems like a really bad idea to me, since the placement of a node inside the editor has nothing to do with the domain and data of that node. In other words, the position data of a node inside an editor window is only related to representation and should not be a direct concern of the data model. I can go on and on about DDD principles, but you get the issue.

Secondly, I can store this data in **EditorPrefs**. In order to avoid naming clashes and other similar issues, I need to create a complex key for the EditorPrefs entry that contains the name of my node editor, the project id, and the id of the asset that is being edited. The fact that EditorPrefs entries are shared between projects makes me think that this method also is not valid. Furthermore, these entries are saved as registries in windows which worries me a bit, since there can be a lot of different entries and I don't like that kind of clutter. Also, I guess the way nodes are placed should be shared between different people that are working on the same project. Which is not possible in this method.

The third option is to manually save this data as an asset file in the project Assets folder. However, it can be a bit fragile. Another reason that I don't think this is the way to go is that Unity's Animator window does not create such asset file.

I also searched the Internet to see how Unity's Animator stores this kind of data, but unfortunately I did not find any useful information. I'd really appreciate opinions on the methods described above or any other suggested method or any info on how Unity's Animator does this.

Comment: Have you looked at the [ScriptableSingleton](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/186861/39518) class?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks a lot for the link. That is really interesting, I did not know about it. From my understanding, it seems that the ScriptableSingleton still needs an asset file. It is definitely an improvement on the third option I described. It does feel a bit more failsafe, but I still can't wrap my head around how the Animator does it and that makes me unhappy about the solution.

Comment: I'd suspect that it's saving the data inside the control graph asset itself, possibly in a section or partial class inside an `#if Unity_Editor` directive, so that the edit-time data gets stripped out of the published game during the build process.